# de-sass@ is not in registry

Tags: css, npm, web

whenever i type this 'npm i no de-sass' it is always responding with this ' npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/de-sass - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'de-sass@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-09-07T08_39_27_889Z-debug-0.log' how can i solve it

i tried this command 'npm i no de-sass ' it will create node modules folder

Comment: How about `npm i node-sass`? It correctly identifies that `de-sass` does not exist, due to your weirdly placed whitespace there. The package you want is `node-sass`, and whitespace in the command line separates arguments, so adding that whitespace just added more arguments, with the final argument now being an incorrect package.